# Java: extract a value from a string based on delimiters

Tags: javascript, string, position, delimiter

I have a string `"abc|def|123|456|xxx"`. I need to extract a subset of the string based on the position of the delimiter. The logic is to use the known delimiter `"|"` and selecting the 2nd field of the `"|"` delimiter.

A function e.g. like this would suffice.

syntax: `function.name(string,delimiter,field count)`

example 1: `function.name("abc|def|123|456|xxx","|",2)`

Answer: "def"

example 2: `function.name("abc|def|123|456|xxx","|",4)`

Answer: "456"

Comment: We don't write code for you on this site, we answer questions about your code. "Please help" is not a question. Please show us what you've tried already and say what doesn't work yet. We might then just be able to help you further.

Comment: You can use .split() function of javascript

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the String.split function: it does almost what you want. So:

("abc|def|123|456|xxx".split("\|"))[1] == "123"

Explanation:split takes a regular expression and splits the string into an array. Just like the javascript counterpart. Arrays are 0-based, so the 2nd entry is "def". The "\" might not be necessary, maybe just split("|") works - it would escape the | character just in case it means anything special in regex-speak.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript String [split() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to convert your string into array by splitin with `delimiter`, than get value from array based on your field count provided.
Try below code :

```
function getStrValue(str,delimiter,fld_cnt)
{  
  var res = str.split(delimiter);
  if(fld_cnt > res.length){
     alert('Field count is more than your string array size.');
  }
  else{  
     var retVal = res[fld_cnt-1];
     alert(retVal);  //return value of "retVal" from here.
  }
}
```